# Echo cancellation with PJSIP on Mac

Tags: c++, objective-c, pjsip

I'm building an SIP-based Mac application with PJSIP and I can't set the echo cancellation.

Already tried to set `PJSUA_DEFAULT_EC_TAIL_LEN` at compilation-time to a bigger value than *200* (the default one).

I set the media the EC value through the `pjsua_media_config.ec_tail_len` field, which should be the same as `PJSUA_DEFAULT_EC_TAIL_LEN` (here is the [PJSIP ref](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsua__media__config.htm#a82c1cf18d42f5ec0a645ed2bdd6ae955)).

Also tried to change `pjmedia_echo_flag` to every value: `PJMEDIA_ECHO_DEFAULT`, `PJMEDIA_ECHO_SPEEX`, `PJMEDIA_ECHO_SPEEX` (here is the [PJSIP ref](http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMEDIA__Echo__Cancel.htm#gaa92df3d6726a21598e25bf5d4a23897e)) but that does not seems to have any effect.

Does someone have already succeed setting EC with PJSIP? Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually found a good Echo Canceler library: [bdIMAD](http://www.bdsound.com/products/bdimad-for-pjsip.html)!

With the 2.4 PJSIP version, you can easily plug bdIMAD, check this [link](http://www.bdsound.com/support/how-to-build-and-run-pjsip-2-2-with-bdimad-for-microsoft-windows/) :)

Answer (score 0):

Our experience shows that implementation of media engine in PJSIP is bad. I'd advice to use third party media engine that perfectly integrated with PJSIP - IntegrIT CrystalVu SDK  [www.integrit.com](http://integrit.com/index.php/products/voip/video-engine-crystalvu). It has advanced wideband echo canceller and many other voice enhancements.